# cmake + precompiled headers + object library for msvc 10 is buggy. Or is it?

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2010

I've got a huge cross-platform project handled by cmake whose compilation time was sped up using precompiled headers (PCH) and what cmake calls object libraries which are nothing but collections of object files.

Note that I took care of making PCH and object libraries optional in the MakeLists.txt file which gets interesting since it turns out that turning both options simultaneously using CMake 2.8.10.2 (latest) and msvc 10 RTM triggers a "symbol double-definition" error, which does not show up under any other setup (other options combination with MSVC10 or any option combination with GCC & clang)

```
error LNK2005: "int `anonymous namespace'::defined_twice_if_msvc_plus_precompiled_headers_plus_object_library" (?defined_twice_if_msvc_plus_precompiled_headers_plus_object_library@?A0x57991313@@3HA) was already defined in common-header.obj C:\git\bug\build\common-header.obj  main
```

The code (below) is quite simple: a main entry point (main.cpp), a source file, optionally packaged in a cmake object library, (lib.cpp) whose content should be accessible from the entry point and its header (lib.hpp), a common header that is optionnally precompiled (common-header.hpp), and finally a source file that corresponds to the precompiled header (for the /Yc option of MSVC10, useless for GCC / Clang).

So my questions are:

- Should this code compile under the standard ? I think the answer is yes.
- If Yes, is the issue coming from CMake or MSVC10?

Thanks

---

(fully reproducible with the content below)

Content of main.cpp:

```
#include "common-header.hpp"
#include "lib.hpp"

int main ()
{
}
```

Content of common-header.hpp:

```
#ifndef _INCL_COMMON_HEADER
#define _INCL_COMMON_HEADER

//variable inside anonymous namespace mimics the troublemaking code inside #include <boost/asio.hpp>
namespace {
    int defined_twice_if_msvc_plus_precompiled_headers_plus_object_library;
}
#endif
```

Content of lib.hpp:

```
//empty
```

Content of lib.cpp:

```
#include "common-header.hpp"
#include "lib.hpp"
```

Content of common-header.cpp: (required only for MSVC precompiled headers)

```
#include "common-header.hpp"
```

Content of CMakeLists that provides optional PCH and optional object lib for msvc & gcc is available here (http://pastebin.com/BAdcpzMb)

---